# how to execute a bash command in a python script

Tags: bash, scripting, python

How can I launch a bash command with multiple args (for example "`sudo apt update`") from a python script?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Answer (score 23, accepted):

@milne's answer works, but `subprocess.call()` gives you little feedback.

I prefer to use `subprocess.check_output()` so you can analyse what was printed to stdout:

```
 import subprocess
 res = subprocess.check_output(["sudo", "apt", "update"])
 for line in res.splitlines():
     # process the output line by line
```

`check_output` throws an error on on-zero exit of the invoked command

Please note that this doesn't invoke `bash` or another shell if you don't specify the `shell` keyword argument to the function (the same is true for `subprocess.call()`, and you shouldn't if not necessary as it imposes a security hazard), it directly invokes the command.

If you find yourself doing a lot of (different) command invocations from Python, you might want to look at [plumbum](https://plumbum.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). With that you can do the (IMO) more readable:

```
from plumbum.cmd import sudo, apt, echo, cut

res = sudo[apt["update"]]()
chain = echo["hello"] | cut["-c", "2-"]
chain()
```

Comment: Is it recommended to use (`os.popen` or `os.system`), ex: `res = os.popen('sudo apt update').read()`? @Anthon

Comment: No. If you cannot use `plumbum`, have a look at `subprocess.run()` and use that

Comment: I am using long complicated shell commands, hence using under `os.system()` is pretty easy, where I just need to give command line as input string.  Why is it not recommend to be used? @Anthon

Comment: It starts an extra shell just to execute the command, you don't get any feedback from `os.system()`.

Comment: How about following example: `os.popen('my_command').read()` which returns an output. But as I understand extra shell consumes additional time. @Anthob

Comment: @alper Read 0324 https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0324/. That explains the rationale for making `subprocess` although `os.system` and `os.popen` already existed. Such PEPs are non-trivial to get accepted. Several people have given much more thought to that than you or I ever will. And `subprocess` has improved since 2003, the others are just still there for backward compatibility. Have you red the `os.system` manual page: *The subprocess module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is preferable to using this function.*

Comment: Could I use as with `shell=True` option is it recommended way to use, example: `subprocess.check_output('sudo apt update', shell=True).strip().decode('utf-8')`  @Anthon

Comment: @alper Yes you could. As I indicated that is a potential security hazard, so I don't know why you think that is recommended. And invoking `sudo` is only going to make that more severe. Maybe using python-apt is a better solution (I have not looked into that myself).

Comment: I will use it without providing `sudo` for general commands. I have to use `|` (pipe) on my commands, which I cannot able to use it via `subprocess.run()`. For example command(`echo hello | cut -c 2-`) => `res = subprocess.check_output(["echo", "hello", "|", "cut -c 2-"])` does not see `|`. If you could extend your answer for pipe `|` usage under `subprocess ` that will be so helpful.

Comment: @alper in that case take a serious look at [plumbum](https://pypi.org/project/plumbum/), it is worth getting up to speed with that.

Comment: `subprocess.check_output()` returns byte stream (`b''`), I guess we need to add `.decode('utf-8').strip()` to end of `subprocess.check_output(["sudo", "apt", "update"])` to convert it into character stream. Instead of doing this additional conversion, could we use `subprocess.Popen`  with `universal_newlines=True` flag:  `res = subprocess.Popen(['sudo', 'apt', 'update'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True).communicate()[0].strip()`  to increase its speed?

Comment: @alper If you are on Python3 you need to do that, on Python2 you don't. Please don't use the commenting here as a chat system. If you have a question post it as such.

Answer (score 12):

It is possible you use the bash as a program, with the parameter -c for execute the commands:

Example:

```
bashCommand = "sudo apt update"
output = subprocess.check_output(['bash','-c', bashCommand])
```

Answer (score 9):

The [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module is designed to do this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["sudo", "apt", "update"])
```

If you would like the script to terminate if the command fails, you might consider using `check_call()` instead of parsing the return code yourself:

```
subprocess.check_call(["sudo", "apt", "update"])
```

Comment: this gave me the following traceback : `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Dremor/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    subprocess.call('sudo', 'yum', 'update')
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 537, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 767, in __init__
    raise TypeError("bufsize must be an integer")
TypeError: bufsize must be an integer
` (I'm using yum as I'm using Fedora as main OS)

Comment: You forgot the square brackets

Comment: Also note that `subprocess.call()` is blocking while `subprocess.Popen()` is non-blocking..

Comment: What do you mean by "blocking"? @heemayl

Answer (score 4):

Also you can use 'os.popen'.

Example:

```
import os

command = os.popen('ls -al')
print(command.read())
print(command.close())
```

Output:

```
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 ago 13 21:53 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 ago 13 01:50 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1278 ago 13 21:12 bot.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   77 ago 13 21:53 test.py

None
```

Answer (score 1):

For python 3.5 and more you can use:

```
import subprocess

try:        
    result = subprocess.run("sudo apt update", check=True, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as err:
    raise Exception(str(err.stderr.decode("utf-8")))
except Exception as err:
    raise Exception(err)
else:
    return result.stdout.decode("utf-8")
```

Answer (score 0):

**use subprocess module**

```
import subprocess
command = 'sudo apt update'
subprocess.check_call(command.split())
```

Comment: why am i getting an error when i use it

Comment: subprocess.check_call(["sudo", "apt", "update"])

Comment: CalledProcessError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-33ce645708e7> in <module>()
----> 1 subprocess.check_call(["sudo", "apt", "update"])

/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.pyc in check_call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
    188         if cmd is None:
    189             cmd = popenargs[0]
--> 190         raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    191     return 0
    192 

CalledProcessError: Command '['sudo', 'apt', 'update']' returned non-zero exit status 1

Comment: this error only happens when i run it in a jupyter notebook

Comment: maybe i'll start a new question since this is ot

Answer (score 0):

```py
import os

os.system("sudo apt update")
```

Answer (score 0):

I like @ricardo130's os.popen() [approach](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/462428/33948) because it can handle pipes, redirects, and incremental (realtime) output:

```
import os

with os.popen("sudo apt update") as stream:
    for line in stream.readlines():
        print(line)
```

And you can do whatever you like with the output before displaying the output.
Or use tqdm for a progress bar.
To create a table of the largest files in your git history [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42544963/623735):

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import json

cmd = """
git rev-list --objects --all \
| git cat-file --batch-check='%(objecttype) %(objectname) %(objectsize) %(rest)' \
| sed -n 's/^blob //p' \
| sort --numeric-sort --key=2 \
| cut -c 1-12,41- \
| $(command -v gnumfmt || echo numfmt) --field=2 --to=iec-i --suffix=B --padding=7 --round=nearest
"""

with os.popen(cmd) as stream:
    table = []
    for line in tqdm(stream.readlines()):
        row = [line[12:20].strip(), line[20:].strip()]
        table.append(row)
print(json.dumps(table, indent=2))
```

Which outputs something like this:

```
...
  [
    "51MiB",
    ".nlpia2-data/fake-news-dataset-true.csv"
  ],
  [
    "60MiB",
    ".nlpia2-data/fake-news-dataset-fake.csv"
  ]
]
```